# Generate signals with 0.1Hz resolutions using AD9833 via Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, frequency, arduino-uno

I would like to generate a frequency with the resolution of 0.1Hz from the range of 0.0 up til 1000.0 Hz ( Example such as 23.1 Hz, 100.5 Hz and 999.7 Hz) I have found that using AD9833 we can generate the signal as what I was required, but the notes are a bit confusing to me.

The specification can be obtained [HERE](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9833.pdf) .

Need your kind assist to if we can make the Arduino code.. lets say, to generate a signal of 123.4 Hz via Serial monitor from Arduino and it displayed as it is in the oscilloscope?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the notes, it appears that programming this chip will be non-trivial.  If you don't require frequencies all the way down to 0 Hz, this job can be done *much* more easily with a standard Windows sound card.  (Sound cards are AC-coupled, so won't go below a few Hz.)  For one example, my Daqarta software can generate frequencies (with any waveform you want) at a resolution better than 0.001 Hz.  The maximum frequency will be a bit less than half the sound card's sample rate... typically 20 kHz at the default 48000 Hz sample rate.

You don't have to buy Daqarta to get this capability; the Generator function will continue to work after the trial period... free, forever.

UPDATE:  You don't mention what sort of waveforms you need, but note that if you can use square waves you may be able to do the whole job with the Arduino alone.  The idea is to set up a timer to produce interrupts at some desired sample rate. On each interrupt you add a step value to an accumulator, and send the MSB of the accumulator to an output pin.  You control the output frequency by changing the step value.  This is essentially a 1-bit version of the phase accumulator approach used by the AD9833 (and by the Daqarta Generator).  The frequency resolution is controlled by the sample rate and the size of the accumulator.  You can easily get much better than 0.1 Hz resolution.

Best regards,